# Utilisation du subjonctif passé

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subjonctif

Je suis dérouté par l'utilisation de subjonctif passé. Par exemple dans cet article, on l'utilise pour exprimer une action incertaine, pourquoi on n'utilise pas le subjonctif présent?

> Je ne crois pas qu'elle ait acheté ce véhicule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parce que l'avis porte sur un fait accompli (qui a ou n'a pas eu lieu) et pas sur un fait ou un état présent. Il faut bien pouvoir distinguer les deux ! Dans ce cas, le verbe croire est utilisé pour donner un avis sur ce qu'il s'est passé.

Comment: SVP, pourriez-vous détailler la raison pour laquelle vous avez rédigé dans votre propre réponse :  *...pour donner un avis sur ce qu'**il** s'est passé* et non pas *... pour donner un avis sur ce qui s'est passé*. Quel serait l'antécédent de **il** ?

Comment: Les deux sont possibles. *Ce qu'il s'est passé* est construit comme *il se passe quelque chose*, le *il* est un pronom impersonnel.